# How to implement this SQL query? whereNotBetween problem

Tags: octobercms

How can I implement this query in October?

```
SELECT rooms.* FROM rooms
WHERE '2019-04-07' NOT BETWEEN date_in AND date_out
```

The problem with `whereNotBetween('2019-04-07', ['date_in', 'date_out'])` function in October. It tooks `'2019-04-07'` as column and shows the error (unknown column), but it's possible to do with native SQL (I checked).

Answer (score 0):

Solution: whereRaw("'2019-04-07' NOT BETWEEN date_in AND date_out")

Answer (score 0):

I think your initial query is wrong. The `whereNotBetween` method only works for 1 column in Laravel 5.5 (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses):

`$model->whereNotBetween('column', [$foo, $bar]);`